# Create React App, data via AJAX, PHP page backend on XAMPP Apache

Tags: php, create-react-app

I'm trying to learn `React` by replicating a simple `CRUD page` I created earlier.

The old `CRUD page` was a `Javascript/jQuery front-end with a form`. It sent data via `AJAX to a PHP backend page`, and the `PHP page interacted with a mySQL/mariaDB database`.

Everything was locally hosted on my PC on `XAMPP Apache`, and everything worked fine.

I have now managed to replicate the front end using `React`, via `Create React App` and it's running on `localhost:3000`

I am now stuck. I don't know how to make my front-end (on `localhost:3000`) send data via `AJAX` to my back-end `PHP page` (on `localhost:80` running on `XAMPP Apache`)

There are a lot of us `PHP / mariaDB` types out there who want to continue using that sub-stack as our back-end. The answers to this question will be enormously helpful in encouraging our crowd to try `Create React App and React` (I'm loving `React` btw!). (I was surprised that when I searched [[create-react-app] [php] in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app+php), I got only 2 hits.)

**Update:** if this is off-topic for SO, then I'd appreciate suggestions on which SE I should post this on... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The basic problem is one of [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) (cross-origin resource sharing). The error one gets is (in the Chrome console):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

During **development only**, this issue is easily resolved by adding this line of code to the top of the `PHP` file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

This code should never be left there in production unless you're okay with anyone in the world accessing the `PHP` file API.

In actual production of this React app, one would expect that the `JavaScript` and the `PHP` files would share the same domain, so there won't be a `CORS` issue.